# Java compile time error: cannot find symbol

Tags: java

I have two classes:

- `ImageTest` in file `ImageTest.java`
- `GUIFrame` in `GUIFrame.java`

Both the files are in same directory.
I have instantiated `GUIFrame` in `ImageTest`.
I compile in command prompt using following command (being in the same directory where files are):

```
javac ImageTest.java
Error: cannot find symbol GUIFrame
```

This problem started after I updated jdk.

The source code is as below:
/*GUIFrame.java*/

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class GUIFrame extends Frame
{
    public GUIFrame(String title)
    {
        super(title);
        setBackground(SystemColor.control);

        addWindowListener( new WindowAdapter(){
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent event)
        {
            dispose();
            System.exit(0);
        }
        });
    }

    public void setVisible(boolean visible)
    {
        if(visible)
        {
            Dimension d = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
            setLocation((d.width - getWidth())/2, (d.height - getHeight())/2 );
        }
        super.setVisible(visible);
    }

}
```

/*ImageTest.java*/

```
import java.awt.*;

public class ImageTest extends Canvas
{
    public ImageTest()
    {
        super();
        setSize(300 , 200);
        setBackground(Color.white);
        setLocation(800, 10 );
    }

    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
        ImageTest it = new ImageTest();
        GUIFrame frame = new GUIFrame("Image Test");
        frame.add(it);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paint( Graphics g)
    {
        Image img1 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("DSC_0013.JPG");
        g.drawImage(img1 , 0 , 0 , this );
    }
}
```

I got the answer. I added . to CLASSPATH environment variable and it worked!!

Comment: Where are the codes?

Comment: possible reasons-> you may have not imported a library or mistyped library name. This may be helpful(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean).

Comment: most of the solution to "cannot find symbol" on this site is to place all java files in same directory but in my case files are already in the same directory. still i get this error

Comment: @SURESH ATTA I have included the code, now would you suggest what's  wrong

Comment: I got the answer. I added . to the CLASSPATH environment variable and it worked. Still thanks everyone !!